# How to write a for loop in pandas to create a conditional for previous rows

Tags: python, pandas

So I have to loop through each quarter and identify when a recession starts and ends.

I have developed the following business rules

1. if this quarter gdp is less than previous and previous was less than previous which did’t have a recession flag  then flag recession start.
2. If this quarters GDP> previous and previous has a recession flag or start reccesion mark this recession flag
3. If this quarters GDP > previous and previous > previous but previous 2nd had a recession flag mark these 2 as end of recession
4. Else flag zero for non recession

What I don't know how to do is loop through each row and create an if that will generate a new column to flag if the column is start of recession,recession, end of recession or no recession

How do i do for each row
If the previous row is x and previous row one column to the right is Y
Also if the row before the previous row is x and previous previous row & 1 column to the right is Y?

```
 Output: 
 Quarter GDP  Recession Flag
 1947q1  100  0
 1947q2  110  0
 1947q3  120  1
```

Comment: You can definitely loop through the rows, but it's not particularly efficient. However, you can use the `.diff()` method to get differences between each pairwise rows, or use `.shift()` to shift a column by some number of rows to compare in whatever fashion you like, which is IMO a bit more elegant and encapsulates the logic more clearly.

Comment: post your dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Let `df` be your dataframe containing Quarter, GDP, Recession and Flag. `.shift()` method should work here:

```
df.columns = ['Quarter', 'GDP', 'Recession', 'Flag']

df['GDP_lag1'] = df['GDP'].shift(1)
df['GDP_lag2'] = df['GDP'].shift(2)
df['flag_lag1'] = df['Recession'].shift(1)
df['flag_lag2'] = df['Recession'].shift(2)
```

So now your columns are:

```
df.columns = ['Quarter', 'GDP', 'Recession', 'Flag', 'GDP_lag1', 'GDP_lag2', 'flag_lag1', 'flag_lag2']

def rec_flag(row):
    gdp = row[1]
    flag = row[2]
    p_gdp = row[4]
    pp_gdp = row[5]
    p_flag = row[6]
    pp_flag = row[7]


    if (gdp < p_gdp) & (p_gdp < pp_gdp) & (p_flag == 0):
       return 1
    elif (gdp > p_gdp) & (p_flag == 1):
       return 1
    elif (gdp > p_gdp) & (p_gdp > pp_gdp) & (pp_flag == 1):
       return 0
    else:
       return 0

df['Flag'] = df.apply(rec_flag)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not at my desk, but this might work?

```
df = myDataFrame
prev = None
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if prev:
        #Check if in a recession currently
        if row[2] = 2:
             if prev[1] > row[1]:
                 row[2]  = 3
        #Check for more conditions
     prev = row
     continue
```

I'm on my cell so this really hard to type, but this should get u started.  As u can see iterrows will get u where u want to go.